# Refresh page after update_post_meta

Tags: php, jquery, database, input

I have created a input field on a front-page where the value of the database is on the same page as the `input`-field. If a value is passed to the database I have to reload the page for it to show on the page.

Is there a way where I can automatically refresh the page after the value is passed to the database, so it is shows instantly?

My guess would be JQuery but I don't know how!

M.

Comment: This can be done with jQuery but also you could use PHPs header to do this after the update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code Refresh page after update_user_meta

```
add_action( 'user_meta_after_user_update', 'refreshPage' );
function refreshPage() {
  echo '<script>location.reload();</script>';
}
```

Comment: Also some more info as how it helps OP just giving code isn't much helpful.

Comment: you can try this code within your condition
  ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
<?php